# how can i fix this sfml header file namespace error?

Tags: c++, sfml

i start sfml but can't success tutorial
because of..

[image]

and it says

```
The variable "namespace" is not a type name.
4723 error code
```

What should i do?

Comment: Did you actually declare a variable called `namespace`? Are you using a _really_ old C++ compiler? Is it even a C++ compiler? Can you compile this program:`namespace foo {} int main() {}` ? Edit: Turns out you didn't use a C++ compiler but a C compiler as @Botje noticed :-)

Comment: Don't paste images of your code. Show text. Although in this instance it actually helped...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to compile C++ code as C code. You get an error because `namespace` is a C++ concept.

Rename your file to `test.cpp`.